# parse python arguments getoptserror

Tags: python

Im using GETOPTS to parse a argument.

**

```
def main(argv):
    print 'main = ', argv
    outputfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hw:",["weblink="])
        print 'parsed correctly'
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'parse_link.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'parse_link.py -w <SA or YAL> '
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-w", "--weblink"):
            weblink = arg


    print 'weblink is "', weblink
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**

When I run python test.py - I expect the GetoptError as I did not give any parameter but it does successfully parses with empty spaces

Comment: `getopt` is intended mainly for ease of porting code written in another language that uses the same library. You should really consider using `argparse` (or at least `optparse`) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetoptError is actually for if you put in a wrong option into the example. Using your code modified for myself below:

```
import sys, getopt

def main():
    print 'main = '
    outputfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hw:",["weblink="])
        print 'parsed correctly'
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'parse_link.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'parse_link.py -w <SA or YAL> '
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-w", "--weblink"):
            print arg 


    print 'weblink is '
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

And I run this python test.py -T the output will be:

```
main = 
parse_link.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>
```

You can also see the error by printing the GetoptError as a str as below:

```
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print str(err)
```

Output:

```
main = 
option -t not recognized
parse_link.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>
```

You want to include this in your code below for it to print your usage:

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print 'parse_link.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
    sys.exit(2)
```

Updated Code below.

```
def main(argv):
    print 'main = ', argv
    outputfile = ''
    #Add usage as a string
    usage = 'parse_link.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hw:",["weblink="])
        print 'parsed correctly'
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print usage
        sys.exit(2)

    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print usage
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'parse_link.py -w <SA or YAL> '
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-w", "--weblink"):
            weblink = arg


    print 'weblink is "', weblink
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```